# Why can't I push my local Git repo to my remote?

Tags: git, github

I'm a novice git user and I'm getting rather confused about something. I'm trying to put all of the code for my current project in a local repo and then push it to the remote repo so that it is backed up even if my local machine crashes hard.

I've done the following to add all the files in my project to the local repo:

```
$ git init
$ git config user.name 'My Name'
$ git config user.email my-email@example.com
$ git add .
$ git ls-files
```

The last of those is, of course, only needed to confirm that the files are on the local repo and, sure enough, the files are there. (I probably need to add a git ignore but I'll do that later.)

So now I want to push the local repo to a remote one. I've already set up a repo in GitHub and initialized it with a README. Let's say its name is MyID\vuetify02. I did the following commands, first to add the remote repo, then to confirm that the remote repo was added:

```
$ git remote add remote vuetify02 https://github.com/MyID/vuetify02
$ git remote -v
```

The latter of those commands gave me this:

```
vuetify02       https://github.com/MyID/vuetify02 (fetch)
vuetify02       https://github.com/MyID/vuetify02 (push)
```

So far, so good. This is what I expected and it seems to confirm that it sees the remote repo and is satisfied that it exists.

Then I tried doing this, assuming that I'd now established a connection with my remote repo and established an alias that mapped vuetify02 to the exact remote repo I wanted:

```
git push vuetify02
```

but got this error:

```
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream vuetify02 master
```

Is this git's way of having me establish which branch of the remote repo it is supposed to use for my push? I only have a master branch there so far so I assumed it would default to that if I didn't specify a branch. I'm probably wrong on that though and it needs to be told explicitly what branch to use, even if there is only one. Anyway I tried doing that exact command and got:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/MyID/vuetify02/' not found
```

I'm baffled! Why can't it find the repository? I know the remote repo is there and I can't see any typos in the command so it should work, right?

I'd appreciate some clarification on what I'm not understanding correctly.

Comment: Hi, as you are using https url so that needs to have your username as well. So it seems you have to do: git remote set-url vuetify02 https://<YOUR_USER_NAME_HERE>@github.com/... first and then try (assuming the repo is private)

Comment: @Pankaj Saini - what comes after the final slash, in other words where the ellipsis is? I tried git remote set-url vuetify02 https;//<MY_USER_NAME>@github.com/<MY_USER_NAME>/vuetify02 and git remote set-url vuetify02 https;//<MY_USER_NAME>@github.com/vuetify02 but it said "Not found".

Comment: Running `git remote add remote vuetify02 https://github.com/MyID/vuetify02` produces an error message. Clearly you retyped at least some of these, rather than using cut-and-paste; did you retype other commands as well? The error message you're getting suggests that you ran `git push remote ...` rather than `git push vuetify02 ...`.

Comment: In any case, are you sure that (a) `https://github.com/MyID/vuetify02/'` exists and (b) you have access to it?

Comment: @Henry try git remote set-url vuetify02 https://<MY_USER_NAME>@github.com/<MY_USER_NAME>/vuetify02.git (add .git at the end)

Comment: @Pankaj - Success at last!! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Cheers @Henry Can I post it as an answer? can you accept and upvote, please?

Comment: @torek - Yes, vuetify02 does exist and is a private repo on my own account. Yes, in some cases I retyped commands instead of copying/pasting; I don't remember why but thought I had done so accurately. I'm still VERY confused about these commands though. I *think* I'm establishing an alias of my choice, in this case vuetify02, for my remote repository and identifying where it is but things are still problematic. I *am* allowed to create my own alias, right? Or do I have to use remote as my alias? Do I need to do BOTH git remote all and git remote set-url or can I get away with just one?

Comment: Background: `git remote` is the user-facing command for adding, deleting, and otherwise updating a *remote*. A remote is primarily a short name for a URL (though once you have such a name, you can use it for more stuff than just the URL). The `git remote add` command adds another remote; it needs one remote name (e.g., `origin` or `vuetify02`), and one URL. The `git remote set-url` command changes the URL associated with an existing remote. The `git clone` command sets up one remote named `origin` initially, so that most Git repositories already have one remote.

Comment: So the set-url was just to correct the URL I had initially, which lacked the .git suffix? Okay, that's good to know. I had hoped I could associate the alias and the URL with just one command instead of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the https URL so you need to pass the user details too in the remote url

Please first do -

```
git remote set-url vuetify02 https://<MY_USER_NAME>@github.com/<MY_USER_NAME>/vuetify02.git
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given your remote repository an alias name that you should use: `remote`!
Hence the correct command is :

```
git push --set-upstream remote master
```